# How to tell the channel order only based on the numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have a dataset including 800 images all in numpy arrays. Each image is 256x256 with 3 channels. I want to find the channel order (i.e. RGB or BGR). I don't know how to do it. Since each image is in the form of array so using `cv.imread` or other image reading apparently doesn't help. When I plot the channels separetely:

```
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.show()

x = image[:, :, 0]
plt.imshow(x)
plt.show()

y = image[:, :, 1]
plt.imshow(y)
plt.show()

z = image[:, :, 2]
plt.imshow(z)
plt.show()
```

I get the following results:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I cannot tell the channel order based on the results above, so how do I find the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here...

Firstly, you are confusing yourself by plotting the individual colour channels using the default `viridis` colourmap which introduces new shades of green and yellow and is totally inapplicable to your needs. So, if you are trying to plot a single channel image, just use a greyscale  colourmap like this:

```
 plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Secondly, if the first, *"original"* image is displayed correctly (which I assume is the case), then you can be assured that the image is in RGB order because that is what `matplotlib` uses. It may be that the original image is not what you want - if so, please be clearer about what you know about the image - i.e. whether it should be largely red, or green or that you know it is displayed incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am sure the original image is correct so it is in RGB order based on you answer.